# Can i redirect only my mainpage to www

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect

When i past this code, it redirects my whole website. But when i want to go to ticket.mysite.com it gives me the 404 because it redirects me to www.ticket.mysite.com but i don't want this with a subdomain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have already tried to past a code without the above in the map from the subdomain, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do better to set up virtual hosts. You need at least three from what I can see; a default `example.com`, `www.example.com`, and `ticket.example.com`. You can then place a simpler `RewriteRule` in the default vhost that redirects any request to `https://www.example.com/$1`. Then when the client hits either the `www.example.com` or `ticket.example.com` vhosts there are no `RewriteRule`'s. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html.